# Scan no of faces in the pic and compare

Tags: javascript, java, php, image-processing, face-recognition

I want to write a program that calculates the number of faces in the picture and want to ensure that there is only one face in the picture.

Also, my second requirement is that I want to compare two images and ensure their facial match shows a good percentage match

I have tried 2-3 libraries in jquery and PHP but got negative results.

Can anyone suggest any library or resource that can help in the same?

It can be written in Javascript, PHP, JAVA
Even Python would do!

Please suggest a reliable resource.

Comment: Try  http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-10-face-detection-recognition-apis/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [openCV](http://opencv.org/).
It has a lot of bindings for different languages:

[nodejs](https://community.risingstack.com/opencv-tutorial-computer-vision-with-node-js/)

Also, it has bindings for other languages.